# Application configuration incorrect with Python Imaging Library 

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to install the Python Imaging Library 1.1.6 for Python 2.6. After downloading the installation executable (Win XP), I receive the following error message:

"Application failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem"

Any thoughts on what I have done / not done? The application has not been installed, and I can't import the module through the IDLE session. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like an SxS ("side-by-side") issue. Probably the runtime libraries PIL is linked against are missing. Try installing a redistributable package of a compiler which was used to build PIL.

[MSVC 2005 redist](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=200B2FD9-AE1A-4A14-984D-389C36F85647&displaylang=en)

[MSVC 2008 redist](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=D5692CE4-ADAD-4000-ABFE-64628A267EF0&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

Install Python "for all users", not "just for me".

Answer (score 0):

I got that same message recently to do with the wxPython library. It was because wxPython had been built using a later version of Visual C++ than I had on my PC. As atzz suggests, one solution is to install the appropriate redistributable package. Try a Google search for 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package' and do the download. If that doesn't work, repeat for the 2005 version.

Answer (score -1):

I am shooting in the dark: could it be [this](http://effbot.org/zone/python-register.htm)?